# Downloading an sqlite 3 database in rails as a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I need your help! I Have a simple database that I would like to download as a csv file.

Here is The Database:

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.integer :name
      t.integer :match
      t.string :scout

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to have a button on the program that I'm making to download the database, probably in the index.html.erb.

Here is my Teams controller:

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @teams = Team.all    
  end

  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end    
  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.js
        redirect_to '/team/index'
      else

        format.json { render json: @team.errors.messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :scout, :match)
    end
end
```

I need your help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, but thanks to all the people that posted an answer!

First, you put this in your rails model:

```
def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{number match scout}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    all.each do |team|
      csv << team.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you put This in your routes:

```
resources :teams
```

Then you put this in your Teams controller index action:

```
  def index    
    @team = Team.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv {send_data @team.to_csv}
    end
  end
```

and in your application.rb add

```
require 'csv'
```

If you want to view the code, go to 'localhost:3000/teams.csv' and it will download it as a csv file and it will open in Microsoft Excel(if you have it as your default).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the model attributes and push it to a csv string.

```
def index
  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    # header
    csv << Team.attribute_names
    Team.all.each do |team|
      csv << team.attributes.values
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { render csv: csv_string, filename: 'teams.csv' }
  end
end
```

Or you can also use this ruby gem [comma](https://github.com/comma-csv/comma), which does exactly the same thing as what you need. Add the gem in your Gemfile, install and you can use it like:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { render csv: Team.limit(50) }
  end
end
```

Comment: how will I be able to access the csv file?

Comment: @T.Aloufi Call the index path of controller from view and it'll generate it for you. Something like `<%= link_to "Download team csv", teams_path(format: 'csv') %>`

Comment: the respond_to generates a file in your folder. give it any name you want instead of "Teams(DateToday).csv"

Comment: should it be in "new.html.erb"

Comment: I put it in 'new.html.erb" , I get an error saying "No route matches [GET] "/teams.csv"

Comment: is there any gems I need to install? Also, should the code above be in the teams controller or model "team.rb" ????

Comment: @T.Aloufi it should be in `teams_controller.rb`, and you need to add `resources :teams` in your `route.rb` file. And you don't need to install any gem if you're going with first option, need to install `comma` for second.

Comment: You access the file by clicking on it and it will open in excel or whatever program associated with csv files. The only reason to generate a csv file is to access the data outside of your Rails app.

Comment: I still get an error saying "
ActionController::UnknownFormat in TeamController#index
" And it highlights this line "     respond_to do |format| "

Comment: @TomConnolly do l put anything in my routes? Because when l click the link is says that there is no route for "teams.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your model:

```
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w{name match scout}
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes

  all.each do |team|
    csv << team.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
  end
end
end
```

Then in your view (add index action in controller):

```
<%= link_to "CSV", teams_path(format: "csv") %>
```

Then in your controller add under

```
@teams = Team.all
  format.csv { send_data @teams.to_csv, filename: "Teams-#{Date.today}.csv"
```

And you should be good to go. You may need to add the index action to your routes if you didn't use "resources"

Comment: I get this error when l try to go to the index page "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting "